# Error when populating array in async task

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my iOS Swift app I populate 2 arrays with an async task in this way:

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        for n: Node in DataManager.sharedInstance.allNodes {

            locationNode = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: n.Lat, longitude: n.Lon)

            if locationNode.latitude < ne.latitude && locationNode.longitude < ne.longitude && locationNode.latitude > sw.latitude && locationNode.longitude > sw.longitude {

                self.listVisibleNodes.append(n)

                // Declare the marker `hello` and set its coordinates, title, and subtitle
                let hello = CustomPointAnnotation()
                hello.coordinate = locationNode
                hello.title = n.Label
                hello.subtitle = n.Net+"_"+String(n.Id)
                hello.imageName = n.Label

                self.visibleMarkersOnMap.append(hello)
            }     
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            // update some UI
            mapView.addAnnotations(self.visibleMarkersOnMap)  
        }
      }
```

As you can see, I append values to an array on 2 places. Sometimes I get an error while running this code, not always. Once I had this **fatal error**:

> UnsafeMutablePointer.destroy with negative count

And sometimes I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What error you are getting and on which line ? What is `ne` ?

Comment: How did you declare the two arrays and what is mapView (how is it declared)

Comment: ne and sw are corners on the map (North East, South West). The code checks to see if the location in inside the bounds of these corners.

Comment: This is how I declare the 2 arrays: var listVisibleNodes: [Node] = [Node]() and var visibleMarkersOnMap: [MKPointAnnotation] = [MKPointAnnotation](). Lou is right: ne and se are the corners of the map. I get the errors on the lines where I append items to listVisibleNodes and visibleMarkersOnMap.

Comment: Arrays are not thread safe. Since you are dispatching your array updates into the background the arrays are going to suffer concurrent updates.  It looks like you are just creating the array from local data or data that is already in memory, so is unlikely to be a particularly slow operation. Try without the the dispatch async on to the background task first. If you still want to do it in the background then you need to guard your array updates with some sort of lock such as https://github.com/ide/Synchronized